# Escape an ActiveRecord transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

How can I escape an *ActiveRecord* transaction? Consider the following code:

```rb
Model1.transaction do
  response = http.request(request)
  OutboundRequestLog.create(request:, response:)

  # … do stuff with Model1

  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

`OutboundRequestLog` is an *ActiveRecord* model and should be persisted independently of the `Model1` transaction. The code above will cause the `OutboundRequestLog` to be rolled-back as well.

Is it possible somehow to somehow exclude queries from the current transaction?
I tried the following already:

1. Acquire a new database connection

   ```rb
   Thread.new do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      OutboundRequestLog.create(request:, response:)
    end
   end.value
   ```

   The disadvantage here is that Capybara doesn't seem to cope well. I'm not sure whether the problem are transactional fixtures or the executor thread.
2. To delay the logging via an *ActiveJob#perform_later* is not easy because net/http requests are not easily serializable and the serialized payload could be huge.

Comment: Any reason you can't create the log before entering the transaction?

Comment: The design of the thing is a bit more complex than I depicted here. It involves complex AR validations and a whole cascade of other models and HTTP requests.

Comment: I added what I ended up with to here: https://github.com/renuo/rails_api_logger/blob/main/README.md#caveats

Answer (score 2):

Btw, it's not generally a good idea to put things that take a long time (long time in terms of DB world, ie. anything more than ~ a few dozen milliseconds) inside a DB transaction, eg. an HTTP request. You should do that before getting into the transaction (and therefore you could log before getting into the transaction in your use case), and then open the transaction to do just the DB related things.

Other options would be to configure your `OutboundRequestLog` model with a `connects_to` clause to use a different DB connection ([see more here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html)), or you can [manually `checkout`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html#method-i-checkout) a connection, just know that you need to check it back in. I'd hide that complexity inside a `OutboundRequestLog` method.

Although it's mostly used for replicas and sharding, I'd generally use the `connects_to` approach. It's neater and less manual (and honestly, if I was logging to the DB I'd always be thinking that eventually I'll want a dedicated DB for that so I'm not impacting my user's experience)

Comment: Cool idea using `connects_to`. I read it up it. It should work out-of-the box because
`Rails uses the model class name for the connection specification name`
but it doesn't seem to be intended
`It's important to connect to your database in a single model and then inherit from that model for the tables rather than connect multiple individual models to the same database.`

Can you elaborate further on the point about why DB transactions should not take long? I don't see a problem if I don't lock and the scope is narrow.

Comment: Yeah, because the longer a transaction is open for, the more likely it is that you'll get a serialization failure on commit.